# Create a domain for windows server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, dns, vmware

i'm trying to install vmware view connection server but is ask me that the computer does not belong to a domain.

what do i do now? this is a home server and i do have a static ip address with my isp. the aim would be to connect from outside my home network remotely.

do i need to add a dns server in windows server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [LogMeIn](http://logmein.com/)?  The free edition works beautifully for this sort of thing, without the headaches of firewalls, DNS, and IP addresses.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need a AD domain to install vmware view connection server.

Please refer to pre-req of view:[vmware view install guide](https://pubs.vmware.com/view-50/index.jsp#com.vmware.view.installation.doc/GUID-F6075DF0-9614-4A81-B27A-7EE7C4CCB46F.html)

Preparing Active Directory
View uses your existing Microsoft Active Directory infrastructure for user authentication and management. You must perform certain tasks to prepare Active Directory for use with View.